# Proving if $(A-B)^2 = (A+B)^2$, then $A^2B = BA^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

When you multiply out $(A-B)^2 = (A+B)^2$, I get $-AB=BA$. I then multiply by -$A$ to get $A^2B = -ABA$. I don't see how I'm supposed to get $BA^2$.

Answer (score 3):

$A^2B=A(AB)=A(-BA)=-(AB)A=(-AB)A=(BA)A=BA^2$